# FIrebase & Run Payments with Stripe - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3

Getting this error when trying to navigate the user to their customer portal after they've signed up for a subscription.

Here is the error message.

[image]

In this case the user has successfully signed up to a subscription and has been authenticated. The subscription start and end dates are showing correctly, but I'm unable to navigate to payment portal for the user.

I was also getting a CORS error until I included `app, 'us-central1'` when calling the function `const functions = getFunctions()` as this was required in a recent firebase update.

```
<script>
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions"

export default {
  props: ["subscription"],

  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async openCustomerPortal() {
      this.isLoading = true
      console.log(app)

      const functions = getFunctions(app, 'us-central1') 

      const functionRef = httpsCallable(
        functions,
        "ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink",
      )

      const { data } = await functionRef({
        returnUrl: window.location.origin,
      })

      window.location.assign(data.url)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Subscribed Account</h2>
      
      <div
        v-if="subscription.cancel_at_period_end"
        class="alert alert-warning"
      >
        This subscription will cancel at the end of the period.
      </div>
      <p>
        Current period start:
        {{
          new Date(
            subscription.current_period_start.seconds * 1000
          ).toLocaleString()
        }}
      </p>

      <p>
        Current period end:
        {{
          new Date(
            subscription.current_period_end.seconds * 1000
          ).toLocaleString()
        }}
      </p>

      <button
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        :disabled="isLoading"
        @click="openCustomerPortal"
      >
        {{ isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Open my billing portal" }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Where does `app` come from? It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere

Comment: Thanks @Phil, had to import app. I also had two extensions installed as wanted to use one for test mode and it was taking the region of the first extension which was different to the one included in the code.

Have created a separate Firebase app now to run tests and have got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Had to import app and firebase cannot manage two stripe extensions on the same app. The region was being pulled from the wrong extension resulting in the error.

```
import { app } from "/firebase"
```